# Wordpress scheduled task is called but not executed

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, wp-cron

I created a plugin with a cron to update all posts of a certain type every 5 minutes. I installed WP Crontrol to check if the cron is registered correctly and everything seems to be okay.

This is how I registered my cron:

```
function custom_cron_interval( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['fiveminutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 300,
        'display' => __('Every five minutes')
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_interval' ); 

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'recalculate_all_scores' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'fiveminutes', 'recalculate_all_scores');
}
```

It is registered correctly but when the function executes, nothing happens. For testing purposes I hooked the function to the save_post action. Everything works fine this way. But when the scheduled task is called, it won't execute.

Here is the code of the function

```
function recalculate_all_scores() {
    global $wpdb; 

    $customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
                                WHERE post_type = 'customer' 
                                AND post_status = 'publish';");

    foreach ($customers as $customer){
        set_score($customer);
    }
}

function set_score($customer){
    $acf_key = "score";
    $score = rand(0,50);
    update_field( $acf_key, $score, $customer->ID );
}
```

I also added the following lines to my wp-config.php:

```
define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', false);
```

Any idea what is stopping the function from executing?

**EDIT**

- I'm aware that the wp_cron system is not a real cron and that it relies on site visits.
- If I execute the function manually it takes about 15 seconds so the PHP execution time limit should not be a problem.

Comment: Are you aware the wp_cron is not a true cron system and infact relies on site visits to kick off? Also are you aware that there are execution times in your PHP settings which could limit execution? i.e. A task execution limit may be set to 3 minutes in your PHP ini and if your task is waiting 5 minutes the execution may be getting cancelled

Comment: @CraigPearson I'm aware of that and I updated my question. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue recently, until I followed an example from the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) which suggests using action hooks to run the function.

I think if you add the following...

```
add_action( 'recalculate_all_scores_hook', 'recalculate_all_scores' );
```

...and amend the wp_schedule_event function to use the action hook name rather than the function directly...

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'fiveminutes', 'recalculate_all_scores_hook' );
```

...you might be in business.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't change a thing... In the end I solved it by hooking it in to an existing event.

Answer (score -2):

WordPress only support hourly, daily and twise daily, so change five minutes with any of three and set your function with `sleep(10);` or any other time which suitable for your plugin

Check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)

Comment: That is not true, you can define, as the OP is doing, custom time intervals with the [`cron_schedules` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/cron_schedules). hourly, daily and twise daily are the intervals defined in the core but WordPress supports any desired interval.